# can i listen to a function call using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How can i listen to a specific function call with parametters using javascript:

example : when showname(2) is called i can do something like call another function too, showage(2)

Comment: Just modify the function.

Comment: use a callback maybe ?

Comment: add function call statement inside the function

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can wrap it:

```
var native = window.alert;

window.alert = function(){
    console.log('alerting...');
    native.apply(window, arguments);
    console.log('alerted!');
};

alert('test');
```

### update

you can do something similar with properties, using getters and/or setters:

```
var foo = {
     bar = 'baz'
};
```

into

```
var foo = {
    _bar: 'baz',
    get bar(){
        console.log('someone is taking my bar!');
        return this._bar;
    },
    set bar(val){
        console.log('someone pretends to set my bar to "' + val + '"!');
        this._bar = val;
    }
};

alert(foo.bar);

foo.bar = 'taz';
```

encapsulated (private `_bar`):

```
var foo = function(){
    var _bar = 'baz';

    return {
        get bar(){
            console.log('someone is taking my bar!');
            return _bar;
        },
        set bar(val){
            console.log('someone pretends to set my bar to "' + val + '"!');
            _bar = val;
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Now I remember wrapping console.error to fetch console errors for logging...I also have a unit test for that :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't "hook" into arbitrary function calls, no.

Comment: You can by wrapping the original function, as @bevacqua supposes.

Answer (score -2):

One way to do it is to add a callback to the function, for example define:

```
function showname(firstname, lastname, callback){
    alert(firstname + lastname);
    if(callback) callback();
}

function showage(){ 
   alert("who's age?");
}
```

And call:

```
showname("John", "Doe", showage);
```

Comment: imo, a callback is not an answer to the question "can i listen to a function call using javascript?"