# listening for a function execution

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have a function `doSomething()` that can be triggered by 
many different DOM events.
Is it possible to listen not to an event, but to a moment, when that function is being called/ listen to a function execution?

I mean - I cannot edit the original function and looking for a solution on don't want to reapeat everything attatching another function to all those events.

Comment: Are you able to change the points at which this function is being called? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759523/can-i-listen-to-a-function-call-using-javascript) suggests that it isn't possible to hook onto _just_ a function call.

Answer (score 4):

If it's possible to override the function, you can store the original, override it, then call the original. I've set this up to use `rxjs` as it's in the tags for the question, but the principle of this applies with or without it.

```js
const DO_SOMETHING_EVENT_NAME = 'doSomething called';

function doSomething() {
  console.log('doing something');
}


var doSomethingOriginal = doSomething;
window.doSomething = function () {
  var event = new Event(DO_SOMETHING_EVENT_NAME);
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
  doSomethingOriginal();
};

var observable = rxjs.fromEvent(document, DO_SOMETHING_EVENT_NAME);

observable.subscribe(() => console.log('doing something else'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<button onclick="doSomething()">First</button>
<button onclick="doSomething()">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950120/catch-listen-to-functions-execution) you need something that implements "aspect oriented programming (AOP)" https://github.com/cujojs/meld